# Error syntax "LIMIT" subquery with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a subquery. For some purposes (i have to manipulate data with the js library DataTables), i need to put a subquery in my query. But when i try to do this, i get a syntax error.

Essentially, i have two tables:

**TABLES**

*WW_PS_ORDERS*

```
| id_order| reference| total_paid| date_add| id_cart|

|:------- |:--------:| ---------:| -------:| ------:|

| 1       | ABCDEF   | 10        |2022-01-01| 15
```

*SMARTY*

```
| ID_PS| identificativo_ordine|

|:-    |:--------------------:| 

| 15    |  ABCDJEHR          |
```

So, for get all fields of first table, and the field 'identificativo_ordine' of second table, i made this request:

```
SELECT en.id_order, en.reference, en.total_paid, en.date_add, 
        s.identificativo_ordine, en.id_cart
from develettronw.ww_ps_orders en 
    inner join smarty.orders s on en.id_order = s.id_ps
order by en.date_add desc
```

But ideally i need to do something like that:

```
SELECT id_order, 
        reference,total_paid,date_add,identificativo_ordine,id_cart 
FROM (
        SELECT en.id_order, en.reference, en.total_paid, 
                en.date_add, s.identificativo_ordine, en.id_cart
        from develettronw.ww_ps_orders en 
            inner join smarty.orders s on en.id_order = s.id_ps
      )
```

But i get a "syntax error" caused by LIMIT, but i have no LIMIT in my request. Why?

> #1064 - Errore di sintassi nella query SQL vicino a 'LIMIT 0,25' line 5

.. which roughly translated means

> #1064 - Syntax error in sql query near 'limit 0 25' line 5

Comment: Then are you sure it is this query that is giving you this error

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that error message resembles those generated by PhpMyAdmin. Your DB tool might be trying to paginate results.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, is too strange. I'm on phpmyadmin. He talk about LIMIT but there is not limit! lol

Yes, on phpmyadmin. I have to change DB tools ?

Comment: *But ideally i need to do something like that* No problems. Simply add an alias to the subquery. *i get a "syntax error" caused by LIMIT, but i have no LIMIT in my request. Why?* Because server have found LIMIT clause (added by PhpMyAdmin) instead of the alias. So server decides that LIMIT word is an alias - but this keyword is reseved. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L This causes an error.

Comment: @Akina yes that's work! Can you explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL client is trying to paginate results automagically. The query is not valid in the first place, and the paginated query is not valid either. Your query would throw:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

... because you forgot to define an alias for the subquery. It should be:

```
SELECT id_order, 
        reference,total_paid,date_add,identificativo_ordine,id_cart 
FROM (
        SELECT en.id_order, en.reference, en.total_paid, 
                en.date_add, s.identificativo_ordine, en.id_cart
        from develettronw.ww_ps_orders en 
            inner join smarty.orders s on en.id_order = s.id_ps
      ) some_alias_here --> You missed this
```

Appending `LIMIT` has the side effect of masking the actual error.